# Is there an easy way to push git changes to a Subversion repository with more than one address?

Tags: git, svn

We are starting to use git, and liking it, but have an existing Subversion respository.

Is it possible to push changes to svn from git where the url to svn is one of several values? (The url from inside the company is different from outside.)

It would be the **same** repository but being accessed via **different** urls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git` with `svn` with [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) which lets you `commit` and `rebase` your local `git` repo with a `svn` repository.

Regarding the `svn` repo identified by two different urls, as you said is the same repository, so I would suggest you to create an "network alias" in your OS, so the url is always the same for git, and you can make it point to one or other url based on your connection (inside or outside the company network).
In *unix you can do that by editing the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: I am using git svn. I decided to use ssh port forwarding, since the original repo url for svn is svn://localhost/myrepo/.